# error: no viable conversion from 'std::array<int, n>' to 'const void *' using SYCL/DPC++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, sycl, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I am a beginner in SYCL/DPC++. I have written a code using USM(Unified Shared Memory) and have taken two array host and device array in which I want to copy the host array values to device array and performing basic operations and printing the values.
But at the time of compilation, I got an error.

Here is my code.

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <array>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sycl;
const int n = 6;

int main() {
  queue q;

  std::array<int,n> h_a;
  int *d_a = malloc_device<int>(n, q);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    h_a[i] = n;

  q.submit([&](handler& h) {
      h.memcpy(d_a,h_a,n * sizeof(int));
    });
  q.wait();

  q.submit([&](handler& h) {
      h.parallel_for(n, [=](id<1> i) {
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] * 2;
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] + 2;
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] - 2;
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] + 2;
        });
    });
  q.wait();

  q.submit([&](handler& h) {
      h.memcpy(h_a,d_a,n * sizeof(int));
    });
  q.wait();
  for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    cout<<h_a[i]<<" "<<d_a[i]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<"\n";

  free(d_a, q);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation Error

```
simpleope.cpp:17:20: error: no viable conversion from 'std::array<int, n>' to 'const void *'
      h.memcpy(d_a,h_a,n * sizeof(int));
                   
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.3.0/linux/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:2171:39: note: passing argument to parameter 'Src' here
  void memcpy(void *Dest, const void *Src, size_t Count);
                                      
simpleope.cpp:32:16: error: no viable conversion from 'std::array<int, n>' to 'void *'
      h.memcpy(h_a,d_a,n * sizeof(int));
               
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2021.3.0/linux/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/handler.hpp:2171:21: note: passing argument to parameter 'Dest' here
  void memcpy(void *Dest, const void *Src, size_t Count);
                    
2 errors generated.
```

Can someone help me where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ->`h_a.data()`?

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42 I got where I missed it thanks again for looking into my code it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for memcpy() is

```
`void memcpy(void *Dest, const void *Src, size_t Count);`
```

You need to pass the second parameter as pass by reference not pass by value. You can pass &h_a (or) &h_a[0] (or) h_a.data() any of these as a parameter to remove those errors in your code.
The modified code is

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <array>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace sycl;
const int n = 6; int main() {​​​​
  queue q;   std::array<int,n> h_a;
  int *d_a = malloc_device<int>(n, q);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    h_a[i] = n;   
q.submit([&](handler& h) {​​​​
      h.memcpy(d_a,&h_a,n * sizeof(int));
    }​​​​);
  q.wait();   
q.submit([&](handler& h) {​​​​
      h.parallel_for(n, [=](id<1> i) {​​​​
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] * 2;
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] + 2;
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] - 2;
          d_a[i] = d_a[i] + 2;
        }​​​​);
    }​​​​);

  q.wait();   
q.submit([&](handler& h) {​​​​
      h.memcpy(&h_a,d_a,n * sizeof(int));
    }​​​​);
  q.wait();
  for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){​​​​
    cout<<h_a[i]<<" "<<d_a[i]<<" ";
  }​​​​
  cout<<"\n";   free(d_a, q);
  return 0;
}​​​​
```